# Windows Phone 8.1 DatePicker control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have Multi Language app in English and Arabic. I have datepicker control also. Now when change my app language to Arabic, DatePicker control calendar will become arabic that is correct behaviour but it is possible to keep English calendar even though it is Arabic culture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows phone when user changes languages phone loads(replace previous) language resource for all the controls and you cannot change/override current language of the control. So it is not possible by using default date picker control